Modify XML files before / after mergeResources task
In my Android Studio project, I'm trying to minify XML files in the release / debug package only.
Problem is, when I try to minify xml after mergeResources task, they are flatenized by AAPT2 (.xml.flat)
Right now I'm using
    val minifyTask = tasks.register<Exec>("minifyTask") {
        workingDir = File("build/intermediates/merged_res/debug/mergeDebugResources")
        commandLine("minify", "-r", "-o", ".", ".")
    }
    applicationVariants.all {
        minifyTask.dependsOn(mergeResourcesProvider)
        packageApplicationProvider.dependsOn(minifyTask)
    }

so the task runs after mergeResources but before package task.
Unfortunately, .xml.flat files cannot be modified and... appt2 can't be disabled as of 2024.
Is there any way I could modify (minify) xml before mergeResources task?
